# Need some clarification regarding normal approximation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

If we have a point estimate (for example sample mean) $\hat{\theta}$ of $n$ observations , why is it that $$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\sqrt{s^{2}}} \not \in t(n-1)$$ but instead $$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\sqrt{s^{2}/n}} \in t(n-1)$$
Isn't $\hat{\sigma}^{2}=s^{2}$?

I've seen this in a textbook $$\frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\sqrt{\sigma^{2}}} \in N(0,1)$$
Why is it enough to divide by the standard deviation sometimes, but other times you have to divide with the standard deviation over the square root of $n$ ? Even if in both cases you have $n$ observations?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a matter of notation.

When you sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from a normal population $X\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ (i.e., each single $X_i$ has mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2$), the sample mean follows a normal distribution, too, with mean $\theta$ and variance $V(\hat\theta)=\sigma^2/n$.

Then, standardizing yields that
$$
\frac{\hat\theta-\theta}{\sqrt{V(\hat\theta)}}=\frac{\hat\theta-\theta}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}\sim N(0,1)
$$
Replacing $\sigma^2$ by its estimate $s^2$ turns this $N(0,1)$-distribution into a $t(n-1)$, as discussed in any introductory textbook.

Hence, your last display may have arisen as shorthand notation $\sigma^2=\sigma^2/n$.